# Cakephp query to get last single field data from multi user

Tags: sql, cakephp, orm, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-2.6

I have a table called `Transaction` with relation `User`, Transaction has a field called `balance`.

Data looks like:

```
id  user_id  balance 
1   22       365
2   22       15
3   22       900
4   32       100
4   32       50
```

I need all users associative data and last insert balance field of `User`. For example here `id=3` is last inserted data for `user_id=22`.

In raw SQL I have tried this:

```
select * from transactions where id in (select max(id) from transactions group by user_id)
```

If I add here a inner join I know I can also retrieve User data. But how can I do this in CakePHP?

Comment: Just write an efficient SQL statement and use Cakephp's [query method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query). There is not an easy / visually pleasing/ easy to maintain way to implement via `find`. IMO: You're better off using `query` and writing good comments.

Comment: I know about query method but I want to apply it in cakephp format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, [subqueries](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries) are ugly in CakePHP 2.x. You may as well hard code the SQL statement and execute it through `query()`, as suggested by @AgRizzo in the comments.

However, when it comes to retrieving the last (largest, oldest, etc.) item in a group, there is a more elegant solution.

In this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ae1c/3), I've applied the technique described in

- [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group#1313293)

The CakePHP 2.x equivalent would be:

```
$this->Transaction->contains('User');

$options['fields'] = array("User.id", "User.name", "Transaction.balance");

$options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'transactions',
        'alias' => 'Transaction2',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Transaction2.user_id = Transaction2.user_id',
            'Transaction.id < Transaction2.id'
        )
    ),
);

$options['conditions'] = array("Transaction2.id IS NULL");

$transactions=$this->Transaction->find('all', $options);
```

Comment: You need to compare the id column, not the balance column.

Comment: @AgRizzo You are right, don't know why I got mixed up. Edited the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Is it secure if I use query () ?

Comment: It's secure, as long as you don't open it up to possible SQL injection vulnerabilities. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).